Writing STM32 GPIO Registers in STM32CubeIDE while debugger is running
I'm trying to write GPIO Registers from SFRs tap of STM32CubeIDE while debuggers is running but encounter the error shown in image1. Is it possible to do this?(Other known IDEs like Keil MDK-ARM or IAR don't support bitwise operations in debugger)

I can add Registers in Live Expressions and change them but not bitwise, which make debugging hard due to need for calculation of bit position in mind! as shown in image2


as far as I'm aware, you can't write stuff to registers while the processor is running. You have to pause the processor. As for editing hex, it takes some practice, but eventually you will flip & move bits in hex pretty easily in your mind. A little patience.

Thank you @Ilya. I got used to do what you say in Keil IDE, but not in STM32CubeIDE. Now your comment make me convinced to act like before rather than looking for new
and easy method.
